# CygWin tmp folder is taking too much disk space

Tags: cygwin, directory, tmp

I noticed that CYGWIN /tmp folder is taking too much disk space ( around 10 gb ). I have the program installed for about 2 years.

I googled for a while and I didn't found any help in cleaning this folder. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

what is the issue with

```
cd /tmp 
rm -r *
```

Comment: Hi, matzeri, I thought about doing this but I was afraid that this folder could contain important files, and if I delete it all, cygwin would crash. Maybe I´ll transfer this files to another location and use the program for a while before deleting it.

Comment: data needed by program are placed in `/var`, nothing in `/tmp` should be used for other runs

Comment: I have removed the /tmp folder contents for a while and the program is still working great. Thanks, it saved me 10gb! : )